# Delete lines that only contain specific words

Tags: replace, notepad++, line

I have a big text file(message log from discord, preparing it to use in ML)
There can be content like this :

```
username1
@username2, whats up
username2
username1, im good, and username3 is also doing well
```

(the amount of unique usernames is relativly small, so i can eaasly manually find replace them, and names are more real and dont have numbers in them)
The problem is, I need to delete the lines, where is only `username`, and nothing else.
so here it would be

```
@username2, whats up
username1, im good, and username3 is also doing well
```

blackground : The library im using is treating each line as seperate text, so if undeleted, it would like to generate usernames, not messages, because of shear quantity of header names

better example, taken from actual file :

```
adyos
He reacted to invitation
adyos
And by  the way, basic nightbot commands are up
adyos
And...
Captain Lea Skywalker
MEE6 is better, adyos
```

excepted :

```
He reacted to invitation
And by  the way, basic nightbot commands are up
And...
MEE6 is better, adyos
```

Comment: What is the expected output from the second example?

Comment: How to distinguish between usernames and other text?

Comment: for Tim Biegeleisen :

edited to post now

For Toto : I will find and replece for each name mannually, there are like 10 max

Answer (score 0):

If I well understand your needs and if you have a small number of usernames, you can use the following:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^(?:adyos|user2)$\R?`
- Replace with: `LEAV EMPTY`
- **CHECK** *Match case*
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^           # beginning of line
    (?:         # non capture group
        adyos       # username 1
      |           # OR
        user2       # username 2
    )           # end group, you can add all your usernames separated by a pipe |
$           # end of line
\R?         # optional linebreak
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Comment: Thank you ! I managed to get something working, but it was bad, this is so much better. Thats an overkill answer to me, thanks a lot !

Comment: @TabletkaTabletkova: You're welcome, glad it helps. Feel free to mark the answer as accepted, [How to accept an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)